# How to get the URI link to WAV file after compilation?

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, wav

Currently experimenting with WPF here. I'm trying to use URI files to stock music in a table.

It currently works, but as expected only on my computer as it is an absolute path:

`private readonly Uri[] SoundsTable = new Uri[] { new Uri(@"C:\Users\damie\Desktop\repos2\Tetrics\Tetrics\Assets\music_theme.wav"), new Uri(@"C:\Users\damie\Desktop\repos2\Tetrics\Tetrics\Assets\line_clear.wav"), };`

I'm running into a problem where I can't access my music files after compiling. I can't use a relative path or determine it getting the Path.CurrentDirectory() (because my asset folder isn't generated in the compiled project).

I don't have this problem for images that can be stocked in my DLL:

`private readonly ImageSource[] tileImages = new ImageSource[] {

```
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/TileEmpty.png", UriKind.Relative)),
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/TileCyan.png", UriKind.Relative)),
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/TileBlue.png", UriKind.Relative)),
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/TileOrange.png", UriKind.Relative)),
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/TileYellow.png", UriKind.Relative)),
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/TileGreen.png", UriKind.Relative)),
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/TilePurple.png", UriKind.Relative)),
 new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/TileRed.png", UriKind.Relative))
```

};`

Does anyone have any idea of what to do here ?

I have tried to change my IDE properties for the music files, like build action and copy to output folder.
I think my answer could be here but none of what I tried worked.

Thanks a lot to anyone who responds !

Answer (score 0):

If you looked inside your bin, found the compiled exe and there's no Assets folder there, then you probably haven't set the right properties on your files.

You need an Assets folder in your project.

That must have some files in it.

Their properties must be set to Build action "Content" and Copy to output directory "Copy if newer".

If you do that then you will have an assets folder with files in it within your bin after you compile.

You can then reference those files using an absolute url which would be:

```
 Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Assets", yourfilename)
```

I assume the mention of png files is just to show us something else which is working for you.

However.

There is also a pack notation in wpf which you should take a look at if you are going to reference files in xaml.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: It's working fine for me, thanks ! I think I messed up the path combination, as I added "/Assets/file" and not your way to do it.

Comment: Also thanks for the pack notation, it's great to know and I may implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are evaluated relative to the current directory. In turn, the current directory may be different depending on how exactly you launch your application. It can change during the course of an application session.
In some cases, this is provided by the logic of the application itself. For example, selecting the current folder and showing the files in it. But this is clearly not your case.

You need to get the full path to the files in the application folder (conditionally the folder with the exe file) using the relative path. The best way to do this is an explicit conversion.
Here is an example of such a transformation.

```cs
public static string RelativeToAbsoluteAppPath(string relative)
    => System.OI.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relative);
public static string AbsoluteAppUri(string relative)
    =>  new Uri(RelativeToAbsoluteAppPath(string relative), UriKind.Absolute);
```

```cs
    ... = new BitmapImage(AbsoluteAppUri("Assets\music_theme.wav"));
```

**P.S.** Of course, as @Andy wrote, you must also make sure that the necessary files really exist at the specified paths.